# Online Hotel Booking System, Simultaneous Booking?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I'm asked to create an online booking system with online payment and I'm wondering what to do in the case when 2 customers booked for the same room(s) at the same time.

For Example:
At the same time:

Customer1 and Customer2 booked for a standard room which only has 1 room available. (The Room availability will display that there is still 1 room available). And then they hit the 'confirm' button at the same time.

Comment: Why the downvotes? I think this is a valid question.

Comment: Put a warning at the bottom of your screen that reservations are not final until confirmed, and then give an error message to whichever user was slightly too slow - they're not really hitting "confirm" at _exactly_ the same time, so one or other request will get in first and update your database while the other request should result in an appropriate error message.

Comment: @nnnnnn: ...until the unexpected happens and two requests *do* run simultaneously (in two separate threads). Something like this requires a lock or transaction to be realiable.

Comment: P.S. You can introduce a temporary-hold system to give the user ten minutes to confirm after a room is first selected so that they don't go to the trouble of entering all their details before being told they've missed out, but the same principle applies that somebody is going to get in first and the next person should get a (friendly) error message.

Comment: @Matti - sorry, I intended to imply that the database update would be the concurrency-control mechanism, assuming that the underlying database won't allow two threads to update the same record simultaneously even if the http requests are processed simultaneously.

Comment: @nnnnnn: You still have to code with concurrency in mind. Without any locks, a process that first checks if the room is still free, then updates the status and sends out confirmations will fail since the checks in boths threads might run before the updates.

Comment: @Sirs Matti and nnnnnn: I'm still new to this so I would be researching on locks and threads. thanks.

Comment: @Matti - sure, always plan for concurrency before you start. You don't necessarily need to lock the record(s) though, if your update is only applied where the timestamp on the record is the same as when you previously read it. Either approach works though.

Comment: Yes, a revision ID would also be a quite valid way to handle concurrency.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a locking construct (probably on the database level in this case) to ensure that only one confirmation will go through at once. You should always do this if it's possible to have a race condition like this. That way you will always know who was first, and you can tell the other user that they were too slow to confirm.

Another thing you might want to add is a payment time limit. In many systems, when you confirm something, you will have a certain amount of time to make a payment to  get the reservation. If you don't pay within that time, the confirmation will expire and the room will once again be available.

Comment: Thank you sir... I would try to implement those on my system, I hope I can do those with my current web development skills. I was thinking maybe I could make a table where unpaid reservations will be recorded...

Comment: @KiiroSora09: Either that, or you could just use a field in the reservation table to mark a reservation as "pending". That way you won't have to create two tables with pretty much the same information.

Comment: So in theory if we keep the lock for some period of time it's possible to lock all available rooms permanently by small army of bots, sending booking request every time the previous lock expires? Any ideas how to protect against that?

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of ways to combat this.

1. If I user selects a room, temporarily remove it as available from your web front-end. Then any subsequent visitors will not be able to select that room for booking. If the first user doesn't complete the transaction, then the room becomes available again.
2. Put a lock on the database as mentioned above so only one record can be written at any time

Comment: Sir Martin Thanks for you answer. I'll be looking up on how to put a lock on the database

Comment: I like to express respect for people with far greater knowledge than I have. Especially when they are trying to help. * I admire programmers :D

Answer (score 0):

Use a "provisional" system that marks the booking as provisional for, say 10 minutes. These slots then become unavailable to subsequent requests. If the booking is not completed within the time frame the slot is released again. If you grab all the customer detail before they book the slot then the drop-out rate should stay low.

You must communicate the time-frame and it's "provisional status" to the booker. If you have subsequent stages where the visitor could stop then a simple JS timer counting down the time would help and also push the booker along the process.

Alternatively, allow double booking until such time as the final "pay" button is pressed when it becomes first comes first. The second method would convert better, the first method is more "correct".